# Logging https handshake details with go client

Tags: go, certificate

I have a go application that starts getting a tls decrying error every few days while talking to a C++ server. To debug the issue, I am trying to add handshake logs like what cipher suites, curves, points have been used to negotiate. The connection is mTLS, so it would be good if I can log as many details during ServerHello as well as ClientHello.
I am also looking at the KeyLogWriter to decrypt the traffic, but I still want the above functionality as the issue is very much intermittent, and I have no way to reproduce it.

**Edit:**
Based on @Peter's comments, I currently have something like this.

```golang
client := &http.Client{}
transport := &http.Transport{}
transport.DialTLSContext = func(ctx context.Context, network string, addr string) (conn net.Conn, err error) {
    conn, _ = net.Dial(network, addr)
    // logrus.Infof("%+v", conn.(tls.Conn).ConnectionState) // need something like this
}
client.Transport = transport
```

How to make this work?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Conn.ConnectionState

Comment: This seems helpful. Is there a way I can print these details everytime a request is sent? I initialize a client once, and use it for a bunch of APIs. It would be a cumbersome approach to add it to every API.

Comment: A better question could be, how to utilize this with http.Client?

Comment: Create a [Transport](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) with the DialTLSContext field set to a function wrapping [tls.Dialer.DialContext](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Dialer.DialContext) or similar. Note that many requests may be sent over a single connection, even concurrently with HTTP/2, so "printing these details everytime a request is sent" doesn't seem like a useful goal to me.

Comment: `tls.Dialer.DialTLSContext` returns `net.Conn`, but to get `conn.ConnectionState`, conn should be of type `tls.Conn`. Can you please give an example?   
I am adding this functionality as a flag for debugging. If what you said works, this is exactly what I require. Thanks!!!

Comment: Added a sample above to explain better.